# Get content of repository from SVN using SVNKIT

Tags: svn, svnkit

I want to compare 2 repositories in svn. I try to make program which get contents from svn using svn and then compare local directory. Is it possible to get contents from svn using svnkit without checking out. I do not want to modify anything in repository. Is it possible to exclude some elements like images from downloading.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SVNKit as well as the command line:

```
svn cat URL/file.txt
```

But this means you have to do file by file...The above svn cat can be done with SVNKit as well....

EDIT:
As i wrote you can do everything with SVNKit so the only problem was to take a look into the docs. Ok you can see the documentation of [SVNKit](https://wiki.svnkit.com/) and [here you have examples how to get the contents of files](https://wiki.svnkit.com/Printing_Out_File_Contents). An other good source of information is to take a look at the source code of SVNKit, cause there are complete implementations of the svn command line client in Java with all features.

Comment: User has to install svn in their machine to use svn command line. I am making a simple desktop application to compare repository. User may or may not have svn in their machine. Can you more elaborate on how get data using SVNKIT.